# Json encode with accents

Tags: php, javascript, json, diacritics

I have an hidden element that receives a JSON string from a multidimensional array.
When I try to get this string it returns null because of some accents. The original array is ISO-8859-1. How can I adjust this? It will be parsed with JS to populate a select field.

**PHP - data source**

```
$SubjectListChild1 = array(array ('Code' => 1, 'MainLabel' => 'Dúvidas sobre o processo'));
$data = json_encode($SubjectListChild1);
```

**JS - getting data**

```
var childSubject = (jQuery('#SubjectListChild').html());
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(childSubject);
```

Comment: If someone will need it, than
use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
e.g: json_encode( $data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into utf8-encoding the array strings: [utf8_encode($string)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

json_encode only works on utf-8 encoded data.

Edit: It's possible you can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array, utf-8 encode it, and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it. But I haven't tested this.

Comment: tried many encoding formats with array without success!  json_encode( utf8_encode_deep($multidemensionalArray));
function utf8_encode_deep(&$input) {
    if (is_string($input)) {
        $input = utf8_encode($input);
    } else if (is_array($input)) {
        foreach ($input as &$value) {
            utf8_encode_deep($value);
        }

        unset($value);
    } else if (is_object($input)) {
        $vars = array_keys(get_object_vars($input));

        foreach ($vars as $var) {
            utf8_encode_deep($input->$var);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Sorry. I was trying json_encode(ArrayEncode($multiDArray)); And this dont work as expected. Only work in diferrent executions. $temp1 = ArrayEncode($multiDArrau); $temp2 = json_encode($temp1);  Thks.!